# LSTM connections between cells/units (not timesteps)

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

My question is regarding how an LSTM layer is built, for example in keras:

```
keras.layers.LSTM(units,... other options)
```

Are these units individual cells or the dimensions of the cell state?

I've read conflicting comments on the subject, could someone clarify if all LSTM units or blocks are different units interconnected with a delay of 1 timestep or is a LSTM layer just a cell with 'units' number of dimensions for the cell state?

I've made 3 diagramms, the first is the normal LSTM cell as it is usually shown (feel free to check it for errors), the other two are, as far as i understand them, the other options concerning the 'many cell' layer.

[LSTM normal diagramm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpxdN.png)

[LSTM each cell connected to the next in layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl2rL.png)

[LSTM with all cells connected?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I38er.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Units are the number of cells in your LSTM layer.

```
model.add(LSTM(32))
```

Implies that you are adding an LSTM layer that has 32 LSTM cells that are connected to the previous and next layer. This will result in an output shape of (batch_size, 32), as units also correspond to the dimensionality of the output shape (when return_sequences is false).

Comment: thank you for clearing that up, but is there crosstalk between the cells?, i.e. the cell state being passed on, or is each cell isolated? And since we cannot define the cell state dimension, is it 1?

Comment: There isn't crosstalk for cells in the same layer but each cell has access to what every cell in the previous layer outputs. Passing on states is a completely different story. Normally cells do not pass on states, but for layers like the LSTM, you can set this behavior by using the return_states  keyword.

Comment: So, i've had a look and apparently the dimensions of the cell state is the same as the Units:
This from the LSTM source code for keras
`self.state_size = self.units`
So... the LSTM layer consists of Units number of LSTM cells, each having a cell state vector of size Units with values from 0 to 1 (sigmoid distribution)